# pros and cons on mapquest android

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, mapquest

I have a requirement on building an android map app with options like markers, polyline, polygon and some click listeners. The app must not use google API and instead OSM data can be used. I have a custom tile server and looking for integrating it in the app. I came across Mapquest which similarly offers what i needed. All i have to know is whether i can integrate my own tile server with it or not. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Please read [Ask]. If you have a specific problem with your current code, ask about that specific issue. If your current code works exactly as it should and you'd like to make it more efficient, then present it to reviewers on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you expect people to write it for you, then you are on the wrong site. This is where we help each other, but we don't do it for you. For more information about what Stack Overflow is for you can check [About]. Also, check out the [mcve] to see how to present an example for your question.

Answer (score 2):

Mapquest integrates seemlessly as a basemap using OSMdroid.  Having said that, it needs a key to work.  Below is my basemap switcher (which receives an index for the basemap and switches accordingly).  You may opt to switch between basemaps quite easily:

```
public boolean mapTileServerSwap() {
    boolean flagOK = false;
    String[] urlArray = {""};
    int mapTileServer = SessionPreferences.mapTileServer;
    switch (mapTileServer) {
        case(0):
        default:
            mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.DEFAULT_TILE_SOURCE);
            flagOK = true;
            break;
        case(1):
            urlArray[0] = "http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/";
            mapView.setTileSource(new OnlineTileSourceBase("ArcGIS Online", null, 0, 18, 256, "",
                    urlArray) {
                @Override
                public String getTileURLString(MapTile aTile) {
                    String mImageFilenameEnding = ".png";
                    return getBaseUrl() + aTile.getZoomLevel() + "/" + aTile.getY() + "/" + aTile.getX()
                            + mImageFilenameEnding;
                }
            });
            flagOK = true;
            break;
        case(2):
            urlArray[0] = "http://basemap.nationalmap.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/USGSTopo/MapServer/tile/";
            mapView.setTileSource(new OnlineTileSourceBase("USGS Topo", null, 0, 18, 256, "",
                    urlArray) {
                @Override
                public String getTileURLString(MapTile aTile) {
                    String mImageFilenameEnding = ".png";
                    return getBaseUrl() + aTile.getZoomLevel() + "/" + aTile.getY() + "/" + aTile.getX()
                            + mImageFilenameEnding;
                }
            });
            flagOK = true;
            break;
        case(3):
            mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTAERIAL);
            flagOK = true;
            break;
        case(4):
            mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
            flagOK = true;
            break;
        case(5):
            //TODO 20160509
            // fix copyright and attributions for STAMEN!
            urlArray[0] = "http://a.tile.stamen.com/watercolor/";
            mapView.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("Stamen WaterColor", null, 0, 18, 256, ".jpg",
                    urlArray ));
            flagOK = true;
            break;
        case(6):
            urlArray[0] = "http://a.stamen.com/terrain/";
            mapView.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("Stamen Terrain", null, 0, 18, 256, ".jpg",
                    urlArray ));
            flagOK = true;
            break;
    }
    return flagOK;
}
```

Comment: my tile server is in XYZ.png format Example :
http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" and i need to integrate with my app. I have attached my code with your above implementation here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByXacZESDmJRTzdKWjR6WG5aQW8 . Help me out, Thank you!

Comment: So what is the problem? The XYZ format is the standard format in osmdroid. Nothing special to do to get it working. If you have a specific new problem then please ask a new question.

Comment: @scai I actually need to know how to link my tile server into my source code rather than using mapquest

Comment: @himagaran The example code contains URLs. Did you try to replace them with your URL?

Comment: @scai yes i tried linking above (tony gil's example) and ended up with errors. i have attached the screenshot here : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WfDnd1j0AkR3twgBSzdoFWOl8r1oSvgewSSAFRWlE98/edit?usp=sharing. all i want is to remove mapquest map and replace with mine and im stucked at a point where things need to be put

Comment: @himagaran As already said please ask a new question since this is a different problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153762/discussion-between-himagaran-and-scai).

Comment: Hey tony gil, im getting an error which is unable to resolve on the keyword ".setTileSource" & "SessionPreferences" in your code. Help me out

Comment: setTileSource is a native mathod of MapView class.  Forget session preferences, hardcode mapTileServer to 0, for example.